# Is maximum limit of SharedAccessExpiryTime 60 minutes?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to generate shared access key for a container through code below

```
string sas = azureContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature (new SharedAccessPolicy ()
{
    SharedAccessStartTime =  DateTime.UtcNow,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write | SharedAccessPermissions.Read
});
```

the shared access signature works fine in this case. Client successfully uploads a file on container. But if I set time more than 1 hour (for example 2) I get an exception while trying to upload file on client side saying

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Similarly if I try to set it `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(61)` I get the same exception. Any time less than or equal to 60 minutes works fine.

**My question**: Is the maximum time for a shared access signature is 60 minutes? I didn't find any such thing in any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is documented: [CloudBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature Method (SharedAccessPolicy)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772922.aspx)

> ... You can specify it on a single shared access signature. In this
>   case, the interval over which the signature may be valid is limited to
>   **one hour**. ...

If you want it to be longer than one hour, I suggest you use a container level access policy instead (which can also be revoked).

Comment: Great, Thanks. I must have missed one hour part.

Comment: The one-hour limit doesn't exist with the latest protocol update - see my answer...

Answer (score 3):

As I pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11217273): Starting with the Spring 2012 release, the 1-hour limit has been lifted. MSDN article is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx). For now, you'll need to pull and build the v1.7.1 library on your own (assuming you're using .net) from github, [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/sdk_1.7.1), as this hasn't been released as part of the latest SDK+Tools yet. This version of the library will use the 2012-02-12 protocol version.

Comment: One word of caution: This would not work with storage emulator (:. Storage emulator is still on the older protocol version.

Comment: MSDN article link is broken

Comment: @MAXE - thanks for letting me know. FYI my answer is nearly a decade old, and many articles have moved about (including the link contained in another answer posted to this question). Note: you can propose an edit with the proper link, as an alternative to a comment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon hello David, yes I know it, thank you anyway. I couldn't retrieve a valid updated link, I was only trying to help future readers (like me).